# Asp.net MVC 2 How customize my Model in Framework Entity. Issue For multilang app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4

Here is a multilang table design. Is it possible to add a method for my CategoryText model to give me the CatName for a specific langID. LangID will be chosen by the customer and set in Session variable. 

EXAMPLE :I would like to get the category name like this

```
var a =  _db.Categories.Single(a=> a.AreaTypeID == 2);
string CatName = a.CategoryTexts.GetCatName();
```

**Languages**
LangID PK
LangName nvarchar(100)

**Category**
CatID   Pk 
IsActive Bit

**CategoryText** 
CatID FK 
CatName nvarchar(200) 
LangID Int

Language
LangID    |   LangName 
1   | English 
2   | French
Here is my database structure.

Category 
CatID  | IsActive 
1     | True 
2     | True 
3     | True

CategoryText 
CatID  | CatName | LangID 
1 | Car |1
1 | Auto |2
2 | Chat |2 
3 | Plane | 1
3 | Avion | 2
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string CatName = a.CategoryTexts.
                 Single(ct => ct.LangID == (int)Session["LangID"]).CatName;

public string GetCatName(Area a)
{
    return a.CategoryTexts.
                 Single(ct => ct.LangID == (int)Session["LangID"]).CatName;
}
```

Comment: Fine but it's not in a function. If i'm in the view, I don't think it's the right way to perform this. How can i add your query in the CategoryText model.

Comment: Why do you think it's not the right way? You're using a lambda expression in the line above.

Comment: Ok, if I understand, I should add your GetCatName function in the partial class CategoryTexts.

Comment: That's it. But as I wrote I don't see much need for that. I think you could use the lambda expression directly.

Comment: I'M pretty sure there is a method with the Navigation Property to specify a 1 to 1 relation between the Category and CategoryText and customize the query for the user lang. Your query is ok, but if I need to make a loop throught all my Category, i'm not sure it's a good idea to execute this query for each of them.

Comment: No, there isn't because you need to check the LangID to get to your CatName. This way you must loop through your collection of CategoryTexts looking for a specific category that match that specific LangID.